# Read and decode jpg-pictures

Tags: c, jpeg

I have an old program written about 1990 but modified several times. Around 2005 I started to use a program PixOps.c from Apple Computer to read different kinds of picture files.

It has worked very well until I changed to Apple's new system Mountain Lion. Now I get several errors. Unfortunately PixOps uses a number of routines not available in Mountain Lion any longer.

Can anyone help me how to find a C routine to read JPEG-images from a file, decode them and store them in a simple bitmap? My program manipulates the picture and then the program draws the new picture on the screen. After that I also want to write the new picture back to a file as a JPEG-picture.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a library. The standard for JPEG is called [libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/). It works on most typical operating systems, including Mac OS X.

The project is also on SourceForge, [here](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: A lightweight alternative could be to use [stb_image.c](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c) - single file, public domain C image loading library. Loading a JPEG file is as easy as calling `stbi_load(filename, &w, &h, &bpp, 0);`.